# reply-with history Xpages how?

Tags: xpages

I would create a simple Reply-With-history function that from an XPages with RichText Control (that use CkEDITOR) open another XPages with the history of previous PAGE 
(richtext + attachments + images etc...)

I think that is possible..but I don't know the correct way for this.

Anyone have any suggestion?

Tnx to all

P.S. Think that you have a inbound email document and you create the button **reply-with-history-and-attachments**...the Inotes open a new WebPage with CkEditor that into the body there are the inbound mail...and into the attachment utility ( I think DownloadControl) there are the attachments of Inboud document

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the content of the document as MIME (In case you have forgotten, speak after me: There is no RichText in the Internet, it is a ghost of Christmas past. There's only MIME) using the Mime methods of the Notes document. Then you check what you have: HTML or plain text. If it is plain text, then you just do a String concatenation similar to above but with the MIMEPart instead of the itemValueString.
When it is HTML (as your question suggests) read it with a parser (e.g. HTMLCleaner can read HTML nicely) and then insert your new stuff after you encountered the body tag. Then read the rest and write the MIME back. Would make a nice bean.

Comment: Ok I have there are no problem for read HTML...but for the attachment how can I resolve....and for embedded image..is not so simple...

Comment: Actually it is. Embedded images and attachments are available as other mime parts. You have to include these mime parts too, then it will work. It is quite some work!

Comment: Ok...i don't undestard how can write the parsered MIME into my new XPages with CkEditor control :-( I need to create a temporany MIME field and bind it? P.S. if I insert the code into BeforePageLoad event but seem that don't work :-( –

Comment: You would need to populate the document with the mime before you can edit it. It might require (haven't checked that) that you save it. And I would rather put that into the postnewdocument event of your data source

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would add a parent documents subject to the current one

```
var content = <richTextControl>.getValue();
if(dominoDoc.isResponse())
{
    var doc = database.getDocumentByUNID(dominoDoc.getParentId());
    content += "\n\n";
    content += "=================== Previous: ==================";
    content += doc.getItemValueString("content");
}
```

so this would get the current content, add 2 lines space, add a line to show the end and then its parents content. Depending on your use case maybe put this in a scoped variable and on the click of a button add it to the current document.

**EDIT:**

If you want to deal with attachments to a field you can use code like the below I used in a repeat to iterate through a list of attachments and return links. for your use you may need to change this to use a for loop

```
var al:java.util.list = dominoDoc.getAttachment("Body");
var eo:NotesEmbeddedObject = "";
if(!al.isEmpty())
{
   eo = al.get(index);
   return eo.getHref();
}
else
{
   return "";
}
```

Comment: Ehhmmm ...but this don't work with HTML body...
Imagine an Email with HTML and Attachment....

Comment: For HTML bodies --- there's MIME

Comment: I edited my answer to include code on how to deal with attachments